# java maven test command giving error

Tags: maven, testing, jakarta-ee

when i am trying to execute mvn test command these errors are happening
. i don't know what should i do.

```
`[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ maven-demo ---
    [INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.19.1/maven-surefire-common-2.19.1.pom
    [INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.19.1/surefire-api-2.19.1.pom
    [INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-toolchain/2.2.1/maven-toolchain-2.2.1.pom
    [INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.3/maven-plugin-annotations-3.3.pom
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 26.674 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-03T13:38:26-07:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/19M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project maven-demo: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.19.1 -> org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.19.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.19.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:pom:2.19.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): RSA premaster secret error: SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.`
```

Comment: Please add some more details. Try to write the command you used